# Adding multiple attachments to a mail, in c# windows forms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, email

I'm making an c# and Windows Forms (Classic Windows app like notepad, paint etc.) app that has a feature to get screenshot and send it via mail.
However, It can only take 6 pictures now (I can add more, but I don't want to add more code, I want to make it programmatically), how can I make it send more or less, as set by user, outside of app?

Timer1 sends mail.
Timer2 takes screenshot.
resimoran is an int which is image ratio of resizing, it's 1 by default.
counter is an int, 
It's working right now...

here is my code:

```
    private Bitmap Screenshot()
    {
        Bitmap Screenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        Graphics GFX = Graphics.FromImage(Screenshot);
        GFX.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);
        return Screenshot;
    }

    void SendReport()
    {
        MailMessage mail;
        var fromAddress = new MailAddress(frommail, fromname);
        var toAddress = new MailAddress(alici, aliciname);
        string fromPassword = mailpass;

        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = mailhostaddress,
            Port = mailport,
            EnableSsl = sslenabled,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = usedefaultcre,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
        };
        using (mail = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            Subject = konu + DateTime.Now,
            Body = "None of your businness!"
        })
        {
            mail.Attachments.Add(attach1);
            mail.Attachments.Add(attach2);
            mail.Attachments.Add(attach3);
            mail.Attachments.Add(attach4);
            mail.Attachments.Add(attach5);
            mail.Attachments.Add(attach6);

                    smtp.Send(mail);
        }
    }

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendReport();
    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;
        if (counter == 1)
        {
            Bitmap ekrangor = Screenshot();
            Bitmap imagee = resizeImage(ekrangor, new Size(ekrangor.Width / resimoran, ekrangor.Height / resimoran));
            imagee.Save(@"screen1.jpg");
            System.IO.Stream streamer = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            imagee.Save(streamer, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            streamer.Position = 0;
            attach1 = new Attachment(streamer, "screen1.jpg");
        }
        else if (counter == 2)
        {
            Bitmap ekrangor = Screenshot();
            Bitmap imagee = resizeImage(ekrangor, new Size(ekrangor.Width / resimoran, ekrangor.Height / resimoran));
            imagee.Save(@"screen2.jpg");
            System.IO.Stream streamer = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            imagee.Save(streamer, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            streamer.Position = 0;
            attach2 = new Attachment(streamer, "screen2.jpg");
        }
        else if (counter == 3)
        {
            Bitmap ekrangor = Screenshot();
            Bitmap imagee = resizeImage(ekrangor, new Size(ekrangor.Width / resimoran, ekrangor.Height / resimoran));
            imagee.Save(@"screen3.jpg");
            System.IO.Stream streamer = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            imagee.Save(streamer, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            streamer.Position = 0;
            attach3 = new Attachment(streamer, "screen3.jpg");
        }
        else if (counter == 4)
        {
            Bitmap ekrangor = Screenshot();
            Bitmap imagee = resizeImage(ekrangor, new Size(ekrangor.Width / resimoran, ekrangor.Height / resimoran));
            imagee.Save(@"screen4.jpg");
            System.IO.Stream streamer = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            imagee.Save(streamer, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            streamer.Position = 0;
            attach4 = new Attachment(streamer, "screen4.jpg");
        }
        else if (counter == 5)
        {
            Bitmap ekrangor = Screenshot();
            Bitmap imagee = resizeImage(ekrangor, new Size(ekrangor.Width / resimoran, ekrangor.Height / resimoran));
            imagee.Save(@"screen5.jpg");
            System.IO.Stream streamer = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            imagee.Save(streamer, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            streamer.Position = 0;
            attach5 = new Attachment(streamer, "screen5.jpg");
        }
        else if (counter == 6)
        {
            Bitmap ekrangor = Screenshot();
            Bitmap imagee = resizeImage(ekrangor, new Size(ekrangor.Width / resimoran, ekrangor.Height / resimoran));
            imagee.Save(@"screen6.jpg");
            System.IO.Stream streamer = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            imagee.Save(streamer, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            streamer.Position = 0;
            attach6 = new Attachment(streamer, "screen6.jpg");
            counter = 0;
        }
    }

public static Bitmap resizeImage(Bitmap imgToResize, Size size)
        {
            return (new Bitmap(imgToResize, size));
        }
```

And, please, give me answers in C#, not in English! (not "do this: MSDN bla bla", but "try this void lolnocodezhere() {}")

Comment: Read up on collections http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y3x785f(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<T>`  is your friend.

you declare it at a proper place as

```
List<Attachment> attachments = new List<Attachment>();
```

Then you replace your 6 blocks with a single one where you do a

```
attachments.Add(new Attachment(streamer, "screen.jpg");)
```

and when the right time has come you do a

```
foreach(Attachment a in attachments ) mail.Attachments.Add(a);
```

After successfully sending the mail you delete the collection like this:

```
attachments.Clear();
```

It is up to you to control things like counters, the screen images etc.

Btw: `mail.Attachments`is just such a collection and maybe you want to use it directly..?