# Text/Plain Attachment content show up in body as well as in attachment

Tags: c#, smtp, mime-types, mailkit, mimekit

Environment: Windows 10,VisualStudio 2017,C#
Mailkit/Mimekit version 2.0.1

PROBLEM:Text/Plain Attachment content show up in body as well as in attachment. I do not won't attachment content to show up in body.

I am trying to create mail,using MimeKit.BodyBuilder class like this:

```
var mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("name1","name1@def.com");
mail.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("name2","name2@def.com");
var builder = new BodyBuilder();
builder.textBody = "";
buider.Attachments.Add(file);
mail.body = builder.ToMessageBody(); //PROBLEM shows up here.
```

when I send this mail, iff attached file is of Text/Plain it is showing up in the body also. Note this problem doesn't occur when the attachment is xml,json.

Note, I am not explicitly setting content type as I am following the sample program provided in the MimeKit documentation.

I am enclosing BodyBuilder::ToMessageBody() relevant code below for your ready reference.

BEGIN CODE - MIMEKIT.....

```
   public MimeEntity ToMessageBody ()
    {
        MultipartAlternative alternative = null;
        MimeEntity body = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (TextBody)) {
            var text = new TextPart ("plain");
            text.Text = TextBody;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (HtmlBody)) {
                alternative = new MultipartAlternative ();
                alternative.Add (text);
                body = alternative;
            } else {
                body = text;
            }
        }
```

....

```
if (Attachments.Count > 0) {
            var mixed = new Multipart ("mixed");

            if (body != null)
                mixed.Add (body);

            foreach (var attachment in Attachments)
                mixed.Add (attachment);

            body = mixed;
        }

        return body ?? new TextPart ("plain") { Text = string.Empty };


}
```

END CODE...MIMEKIT....

I'll appreciate someone can point out that problem.

thank you in advance,

regards Atish.

Comment: You can add attachments to ‘mail.attachments’ property..

Comment: Here 'mail' is MimeKit.MimeMessage class object which have attachments property is only get type.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23450852/1662459

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you aren't setting a text or html body, so the receiving client shows the text attachment because it has nothing else to show.

I've changed the code so that if you set the `TextBody` to `string.Empty`, it just adds an empty inline text part as the message body, so now receiving clients *should* just show an empty body.